# JPA query additional group by

Tags: jpa, openjpa

How to write JPA query for below SQL ?

---

```
select * from opstatus o where o.OPERATIONTYPE=2 and o.RECEIVEDFLAG =2 and o.SENDTIME in (select max(o1.SENDTIME)from opstatus o1 where (o1.OPERATIONTYPE=2 and o1.RECEIVEDFLAG =2) group by o1.dn);
```

---

Trying to run the below query

---

```
result = em.createQuery("select o from DTO o where "
+ "o.operationType=:operationType"
+ " and o.receivedFlag = :receivedFlag"
+ " and o.startTime in (select max(o1.startTime)from DTO o1 where   
o1.receivedFlag = :receivedFlag group by o1.Dn) order by o.startTime").
setParameter("operationType","2").
setParameter("receivedFlag", "2").getResultList();
```

---

However during runtime below query gets genereated which has additional 'group by T2.DN' for which we get ' org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression'

---

SELECT t0.OPERATIONID, t0.CURRENTSTEP, t0.DETAILEDSTEPS,t0.DN, t0.OPERATIONTYPE,  t0.RECEIVEDFLAG, t0.REQUESTID, t0.SENDTIME FROM OPSTATUS t0, OPSTATUS  t2 WHERE (t0.OPERATIONTYPE = ? AND t0.RECEIVEDFLAG = ? AND t0.SENDTIME IN (SELECT MAX(t1.SENDTIME) FROM OPSTATUS   t1 WHERE (t1.OPERATIONTYPE = ? AND t1.RECEIVEDFLAG = ?) GROUP BY t1.DN)) GROUP BY t2.DN [params=?, ?, ?, ?]

---

How to prevent additional 'group by' getting appended ? I tried adding 'order by o.sendtime' no use .

Answer (score 0):

Did you means select the last entry in every Dn group. If two different Dn have the same startTime and only one of it is the last(max) your query will fail. Because the o1 in the sub query not linked to the outer o, the OpenJPA will generate `FROM OPSTATUS t0, OPSTATUS t2`

Maybe you can change your query.

```
"select o from DTO o where "
+ "o.operationType=:operationType"
+ " and o.receivedFlag = :receivedFlag"
+ " and not exists (select o1 from DTO o1 where   
o1.receivedFlag = :receivedFlag and o1.Dn = o.Dn and o1.startTime > o.startTime) order by o.startTime"
```